# WCF Trace Logging Not Producing Log Files

Tags: c#, wcf

WCF Trace logging appears to not be working in one of my wcf windows services.  I've used this same configuration in other services and it has worked in the past.  I'm stumped at this point.  Here is the configuration that I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData="C:\ProgramData\Bastian Software\Logs\ExactaManifest\Messages.svclog"  />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData="C:\ProgramData\Bastian Software\Logs\ExactaManifest\WCF.svclog"  />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>

    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="All">
      <messageLogging
         logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
         logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
         logMalformedMessages="true"
         logEntireMessage="true"
         maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2147483647" maxMessagesToLog="25000" />
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

It doesn't appear to be a permissions issue because I manually created a folder and file with the same user that the service is running under.  Also I do see the following in the event viewer related to this wcf trace logging:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: What error is it not giving you, or how do you know it isn't tracing?

Comment: @Greg The svclog files are not being created in the paths specified in the config file.  I started the service and made several calls to it and it does not generate any svclogs.

Comment: Do you have anymore information, so I can try and help you?

Comment: I wish I did but I can't think of anything relevant to add.  Not sure what else to troubleshoot.  If you have additional questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Yeah, it is quite weird that the `Event` exist but the log itself doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried implementing or downloading a `TcpListener`?  That way you can see the traffic or potentially find some of the data as the Service attempts to execute?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The log files will only be created if the directory specified in the configuration previously exists; it's more than just the permissions being in place to create the log file. See this note section from [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Trace files are not created without initially creating the log directory. Make sure that the directory C:\logs\ exists, or specify an alternate logging directory in the listener configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment *"it does not generate any svclogs"* leads me to believe the issue is related to your permissions.  If you are utilizing **Windows 8 Visual Studio will need to be opened as an Administrator.** If you don't, then it will not generate any trace log files.

Some other items you might check:

- Application Pool is able to read / write to your project directory (Security Tab).
- The service is assigned the proper Application Pool to manipulate the project directory.

I'm assuming it is either hosted through Internet Information System (IIS) or being debugged through Visual Studio.  One of those two should hopefully resolve the issue.

On Microsoft's Developer Network they actually add an important note about running as an Administrator in Windows 8 due to how often it is overlooked.

Comment: It's actually not being hosted in IIS.  It's a net.tcp wcf windows service.  I am in fact using Windows 8 but my instance of visual studio was running in administrator mode.

Comment: I also tried running this as a console application with visual studio being ran as an administrator with the same result.  No .svclogs with the same message outlined above in the event viewer.

Comment: @ColeW I'll try and give it some thought, figured I'd start simple before becoming more complex.